# update using prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I want to update my Database

1. When i enter the customer id in jTextbox after that pressing JButton OK then all respective data is extract from the Database is display in the remaining jTextfield in code
2. After displaying all respective database of that particular customer id that again edited for updation purpose then after clicking on the Update JButton all respective data is updated respective customer id

   ```
   import java.awt.Container;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
   import java.sql.*;
   import java.util.logging.Level;
   import java.util.logging.Logger;
   import javax.swing.*;

   public abstract class customer_details extends JFrame implements ActionListener
   {
   JTextField textFieldId;
   JTextField textFieldId1;
   JTextField textFieldId2;
   JTextField textFieldId3;    
   JLabel l1;
   JLabel l2;
   JLabel l3;
   JLabel l4;
   JLabel l5;
   JButton b1,b2;
   Container c = getContentPane();
   customer_details()
   {
   super("Shree Datta Digambar");
   setBounds(140,250,777,555);
   c.setLayout(null);
   textFieldId = new JTextField();        
   textFieldId1 = new JTextField();
   textFieldId2 = new JTextField();
   textFieldId3 = new JTextField();
   this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
   l1 = new JLabel("Update Customer Details:-");
   l2 = new JLabel("Customer Id");
   l3 = new JLabel("Customer Id");
   l4 = new JLabel("Name");
   l5 = new JLabel("Contact");
   l1.setBounds(10,10,340,20);
   l2.setBounds(10,20,140,70);
   l3.setBounds(10,100,140,70);
   l4.setBounds(100,100,140,70);
   l5.setBounds(270,100,140,70);
   textFieldId.setBounds(10,70,70,20);         
   textFieldId1.setBounds(10,160,70,20); 
   textFieldId2.setBounds(100,160,150,20); 
   textFieldId3.setBounds(270,160,90,20); 
   b1 = new JButton("Ok");
   b1.setBounds(100,70,50,20);   
   b2 = new JButton("Update");
   b2.setBounds(380,160,90,20);  
   c.add(b1);
   c.add(b2);
   c.add(l1);
   c.add(l2);
   c.add(l3);
   c.add(l4);
   c.add(l5);
   c.add(textFieldId);
   c.add(textFieldId1);
   c.add(textFieldId2);
   c.add(textFieldId3);       
   setVisible(true);
   setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);                
   b1.addActionListener(this);               
   b2.addActionListener(this);
    }
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
   customer_details eeap=new customer_details() {};
    }
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {               
   System.out.println("You clicked the button");             
   if(e.getSource()==b1)
   {
       try 
       {
           Connection con;                
           con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Dalvi");                                       
           java.sql.Statement st = con.createStatement();
           PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT 
           customer_id,customer_name,customer_contact FROM customer_details WHERE 
           customer_id = ?");                          
           ps.setString(1,textFieldId.getText());
           ResultSet rs1=ps.executeQuery();
           while(rs1.next())
           {                   
               textFieldId1.setText(rs1.getString(1));
               textFieldId2.setText(rs1.getString(2));
               textFieldId3.setText(rs1.getString(3));   
           }                    
       }
       catch (SQLException s) 
       {
           System.out.println("SQL code does not execute.");
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Enter the Detail Correctly");
       }
       } 
       if(e.getSource()==b2)
       {
       try
       {
           Connection con;                
           con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Dalvi");                                       
           java.sql.Statement st = con.createStatement();
           PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE customer_details
           SET customer_id = ? ,customer_name = ?, customer_contact =? 
           WHERE customer_id= ?");                          
           ps.setString(1,textFieldId1.getText());   
           ps.setString(2,textFieldId2.getText());
           ps.setString(3,textFieldId3.getText());
           ps.setString(4,textFieldId.getText()); 
           ps.executeUpdate();
           }
          catch (SQLException s) 
          {
           System.out.println("SQL code does not execute.");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Enter the Detail Correctly");
            }        }     }   }
   ```

Comment: You really should aim for more of an MVC architecture. It's a bad sign to see DB code in a JFrame.

Comment: Can you share the error code or exception?

Comment: Don't hide the exception by simply catching it. In development use `e.printStackTrace()` or use proper logging.

Comment: Ok. I will follow from nowards.@Braj

Comment: Ok. I will learn more things in MVC Architecture.@DavidEhrmann

Comment: this is the error @Braj: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because your field types, especially `customer_id`, aren't Strings. Try something like this:

```
try (
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Dalvi");
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE customer_details SET customer_id = ?, customer_name = ? , customer_contact =?  WHERE customer_id = ?");
    )
{
    ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(textFieldId.getText()));    
    ps.setString(2,textFieldId1.getText());
    ps.setString(3,textFieldId2.getText());
    ps.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(textFieldId3.getText()));
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
catch (SQLException s) 
{
    System.out.println("SQL code does not execute.");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Enter the Detail Correctly");
}
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: this is the error @DavidEhrmann:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: Either textFieldId or textFieldId3 is "". Is that what you expect the customer ID to be?

Comment: textFieldId is for when i enter the customer id for searching data relative to it in the database.after retriving relative data of jtextfield customer id then i update that data and again i stored in the database that why jtextfield3 for updated customer id purpose

Comment: What does it mean for one of them to be ""? You're going to have to handle that case.

Comment: I'm guessing, here. I'd need to see the DB schema to say more, but you're trying to either compare ```customer_id``` to ```""``` or set it to ```""```. I doubt this is what you want.

Comment: Think this through and try some things on your own.

Comment: Hey @DavidEhrmann.I got the solution.Really again my stupidity,error was easily resolve.
Now i am correcting my code again.